# devolver un campo calculado en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo 2 tablas. La tabla Tips que almacena los viajes realizados por un empleado y la tabla trip_expenses que almacena los gastos de un viaje, es decir una relacion de 1 a N.
En ambas tablas hay un campo ammount que almacena en la primer tabla el dinero retirado para el gasto y en la segunda tabla el valor del gasto, ya que en un viaje se pueden generar gastos. Lo que estoy necesitando hacer es devolver en mi array de $data un campo que sea el calculo entre el monto retirado menos el total de gastos.

Migracion tabla Trips

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('trips', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('employee');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->float('amount')->default(0);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Migracion tabla trps_expenses

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('trip_expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->date('date');
            $table->string('company');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->float('amount')->default(0);

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('trip_id');
            $table->foreign('trip_id')->references('id')->on('trips');
        });
    }
```

Metodo de controlador TripController:

```
public function index()
    {
        $trips = Trip::with('trip_expenses')->get();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'ok',
            'data'  =>  $trips
        ], 200);
    }
```

Ese me devuelve todos los trips con sus relaciones, pero necesito agregarle un campo mas a cada elemento donde se realice el calculo

Comment: Para eso podrias usar withSum  https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions para obtener la suma de los amount de la tabla trip_expenses, para luego usarlo en  un Accesor https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators en el modelo Trip donde harías la resta del amount del Trip menos el resultado de lo anterior

Answer (score 0):

comparto solucion
TripController

```
$trips = Trip::withSum('trip_expenses','amount')->get();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'ok',
            'data'  =>  $trips
        ], 200);
```

Modificacion de tabla:

```
 Schema::create('trips', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('employee');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->float('amount')->default(0);
            $table->float('total_expenses')->default(0);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Modelo Trip:

```
protected function totalExpenses(): Attribute
    {
        return new Attribute(
            get: function ($value) {
                return $this->amount - $this->trip_expenses_sum_amount;
            }
        );
    }
```